# Developing app for 10.8+ but using 10.9 SDK

Tags: macos, sdk, osx-mavericks

Mavericks is coming out and for developers that's always a busy time with all these new features and APIs to know about and use. For me, I think it is the perfect time to ask a question that has been bugging me for a very long time.

Here's the thing, in context: I am developing an app that I want to be able to run on 10.8 (so the target system is 10.8+). Right now I am using the 10.8 SDK. However, with the release of 10.9 comes some pretty sweet APIs that I would like to use in my app. I use them in my code, but then, of course, I have to compile my app against the 10.9 SDK. If I do that, **can I still run the app on 10.8**?

Or, in a more general way, if I compile my app against one SDK, can I still run it on a 'lower' Mac OS? If yes, can you explain how does it work under the hood (what is the compiler doing)? This is a mistery for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, Xcode disassociates the issue of the SDK and the Deployment Target of the app.

The SDK is determined by **Base SDK**, and the deployment target is determined by **OS X Deployment Target**.    These both show up in the **Build Settings** tab for each target in Xcode.

When programming with different SDK and Target, you are responsible for making sure that you don't call methods or functions on an OS that doesn't have them.   This is often facilitated by weak linking (in the case of new frameworks) and/or using `-respondsToSelector:` in the case of new methods on existing classes and frameworks.

Comment: But I think there are methods introduced, for example, in 10.8 that are also available on 10.7. How can I know before compiling if the methods are available on each version of the OS?

Comment: That's left as an exercise for the developer.   There are some tools that people have bandied about for checking SDK versions, although I'm having trouble locating an example at this moment.   You can always try recompiling your code with the other SDKs and make not of the errors that it generates, then switch the SDK back and work around them.

Comment: If you have the deployment target set to an older version then the frameworks that weren't available then will be automatically weak-linked. This means that if the app is run on a older version then unavailable weak linked functions will have NULL function pointers, 
unavailable weak linked class names will return nil from NSClassFromString and unavailable weak linked methods will return NO from the containing objects' respondsToSelector: method.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, under build settings, there is an option for target OS where you can pick 10.8. 10.8 applications are generally compatible with 10.9 so the compiled application will work with both OSs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect the new Apis to work when running on a lower version. It doesn't work that way.